# Feature file execution with NUnit

Tags: c#, specflow, nunit-3.0, specrun

I am trying to run a feature file with NUnit Console. I tried googling it and checked NUnit3 help also. But I am unable to find any help.
I want to run either single feature file or any scenario in a feature file which has tag assigned. I am using specflow with specrun. I tried NUnit console command for where "test == path of feature file" but it is not executing test. However I am able to execute all test cases by giving project dll file path. But I just want to execute a single feature file or single scenario in a feature file. Please let me know how can I do this so that I will be able to generate NUnit testresult.xml file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SpecRun then you can use the command line of SpecRun to run the tests.

If you really want to use NUnit then you first have to make sure that the project containing the feature files has been compiled. Once you have a test dll this will contain the NUnit tests just like any other and the test categories will be set based on the tags, so you can execute them all by telling NUNit to run tests in the test dll, or you can run tests which have a Tag by telling Nunit to run tests which are in a category matching the Tag.

Running just a feature will be more tricky as there is nothing which groups the scenarios by feature in the tests I don't think, though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

instead of test==featurefile use name==FeatureName